# table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am appending a new row to the end of a table by using appendrow() , but it doesnt work , can anybody help me .

htm:

```
<body onload="makeTable()">
<table id= "tbl" border="1"></table>
<form>
<input type="button" value=" append a new row " onclick="appendRow()" /><br />
</form>
```

js:

```
 function makeTable(){
var theTable =document.getElementById("tbl");
if (theTable.firstChild != null)
     {
      var badIEBody = theTable.childNodes[0];  
      theTable.removeChild(badIEBody);
}
var tBody = document.createElement("TBODY");
theTable.appendChild(tBody);

var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
var c1 = document.createElement("td");
var v1 = document.createTextNode("HIT6307");
c1.appendChild(v1);
newRow.appendChild(c1);
var c2 = document.createElement("td");
var v2 = document.createTextNode("Internet Technology");
c2.appendChild(v2);
newRow.appendChild(c2);
tBody.appendChild(newRow);

}

function appendRow() {
  var code = prompt("What is the code of subject", "Type code here");
  var name = prompt("What is the name of subject", "Type name here");

  var tBody = document.getElementByTagName("TBODY");
  newRow = document.createElement("tr");
c1 = document.createElement("td");
v1 = document.createTextNode("code");
c1.appendChild(v1);
newRow.appendChild(c1);
c2 = document.createElement("td");
v2 = document.createTextNode("name");
c2.appendChild(v2);
newRow.appendChild(c2);
tBody.appendChild(newRow);

     tBody.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

Comment: what does console/jslint say??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove its " document.getElementByTagName is not a function"

Comment: try document.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function `getElementByTagName` in javascript but `` getElementsByTagName` `` (*list of elements*).

Also, you are filling the new text elements with string constants ("code" & "name") not the value of corresponding variables:

`v1 = document.createTextNode("code");`

```
-->
v1 = document.createTextNode(code);
```

You should write `appendRow` like the following:

```
function appendRow() {
    var code = prompt("What is the code of subject", "Type code here");
    var name = prompt("What is the name of subject", "Type name here");

    var tBody = document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

    newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    c1 = document.createElement("td");
    v1 = document.createTextNode(code);
    c1.appendChild(v1);
    newRow.appendChild(c1);

    c2 = document.createElement("td");
    v2 = document.createTextNode(name);
    c2.appendChild(v2);
    newRow.appendChild(c2);

    tBody.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

#### Demo with row deletion: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqjhj/

Comment: thanks it works. can i select and then delete this row after inserting in a table

Comment: I created an example of doing that with your code (with some modifications) -- deletion is done via button click. See my answer, a link to jsfiddle at the end.

Comment: @maniji i tried it deleting a row when i clicked on the button but how a row can be selected here?

Answer (score 1):

```
function appendRow() {
  var code = prompt("What is the code of subject", "Type code here");
  var name = prompt("What is the name of subject", "Type name here");

  var tBody = document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
  newRow = document.createElement("tr");
c1 = document.createElement("td");
v1 = document.createTextNode(code);
c1.appendChild(v1);
newRow.appendChild(c1);
c2 = document.createElement("td");
v2 = document.createTextNode(name);
c2.appendChild(v2);
newRow.appendChild(c2);
tBody.appendChild(newRow);

     tBody.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

Comment: you should remove quotes in `createTextNode("code");` & `createTextNode("name");`